# Changing route of Cloud Foundry app in Bluemix does not work and leads to app restarting

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Using the new Bluemix UI, if I try to add a new route to any of my Cloud Foundry apps, the app restarts (which it shouldn't, AFAIK). After restarting of the app finishes, the new route is not associated with the app - making it basically impossible for me to change the route.

Is that an error? Is there a work around?

The same actions work fine using the old Bluemix UI.

Comment: Can you please share with us the commands you used? You're correct in that adding a route should not restart an app.

Comment: I used the (new) graphical user interface. Not the CLI.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you do use the CLI?